# NodeJS: How to parse a comment from a CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
# Meta Data 1: ...
# Meta Data 2: ...
...
Header1, Header2...
actual data
```

I'm currently using the `fast-csv` library in a NodeJS script to parse the actual data part into objects with

```
const csv = require("fast-csv");
const fs = require("fs");

fs.createReadStream(file)
  .pipe(csv.parse({ 
    headers:true, 
    comment:"#", // this ignore lines that begin with #
    skipLines:2 })
  )
```

I'm skipping over the comments or else I won't get nice neat objects with header:data pairs, but I still want some of my meta data. Is there a way to get them? If not with fast-csv, is there another library that could accomplish this?

Thanks!

Edit: My current work around is to just regex for the specific meta data I want, but this means I have to read the file twice. I don't expect my files to be super big so this works for now but I don't think it's the best solution.

Comment: What are you currently getting and what are the expected results?

Comment: Quick workaround: You can `fileText.match(/^#.*$/gm)` to get `["# Meta Data 1: ...", "# Meta Data 2: ..."]`.

Comment: Sounds like a custom transform stream should go between the file and the csv parser to grab the comments. The node documentation for `Stream` give some very rough examples of what you need to write a transformation.  Breaking the file into lines first would be a good idea.